# How to assign operations values in Array in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a variable of coins in which different users have different values (e.g. 600, 100). Now, I want an array named selectableCoins which hold values such as if a user has 600 coins then selectableCoins must be `[600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]` & if user has 100 coins then selectableCoins must be `[100]` only. How can I achieve this in Angular please help!!!

```
public selectableCoins: Array<any> = [];
```

```
getCoins() {
    this.amen.getCoins().subscribe(
        (response) => {
            this.handleCoinsResponse(response);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}

handleCoinsResponse(response) {
    if (response.status === 1) {
        this.totalCoins = response.responseData.total_coins;
        console.log('coins sel-----------------', this.selectableCoins);
    }
    if (response.status === 0) {
        this.msg = response.msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your totalCoins value always in multiples of 100?

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.selectableCoins = [];
for (let i=0; i < this.totalCoins/100; i++) {
    this.selectableCoins.push((i+1)*100);
}
```

Comment: not getting the selectableCoins in console. It doesn't go inside the loop.

Comment: Okay I got another problem here. When I reload using ngOnInit() in my code it appends the array with new values like this: [100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300]. I got repeated values every time the code ngOnInit() starts.

Comment: Is there the this.selectableCoins = [] command?

Can you give me your ngOnInit method, maybe I find the problem?

Comment: I got it. ngOnInit is called two times that's why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
this.totalCoins = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]; // let's total coins have this values 
var selected = 500; // suppose use have 500 coins
this.selectableCoins = this.totalCoins.filter(a => a <= selected).sort((a,b) => b- a); 
console.log(SelectedArr); // will print [500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
```

thanks

Comment: coins can be more than that.

Comment: it will come from api right ? i am just assuming that's why given it static